# Memory management of block returned from function

Tags: objective-c

If I have a class function which returns a block do I need to do anything in terms of memory management for the block?

```
typedef BOOL (^Block)(ParamType* param);


+ (Block) makeBlock: (SeedParamType* seed)
{
    return ^BOOL (ParamType* param)
    {
        // do something with seed
        return someBoolVal;
    };
}


@interface SomeClass() 
@property (copy, nonatomic) Block                 theBlock;
@end
```

Do I need to do anything like explicitly in terms of memory management, or will ARC deal with everything in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ARC, you'll be fine with that. There is enough information there for it to know how to manage it.

Syntax is a bit wrong though, it should be:

```
+ (Block) makeBlock: (SeedParamType*) seed
{
    return ^BOOL (ParamType* param)
    {
        // do something with seed
        return someBoolVal;
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between your syntax and mine?

Comment: `+ (Block) makeBlock: (SeedParamType*) seed`, closing parenthesis was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming manual retain/release, that code isn't valid.   You need to return a copy of the block.  You can even do:

```
+ (Block) makeBlock: (SeedParamType* seed)
{
    return [[^BOOL (ParamType* param)
    {
        // do something with seed
        return someBoolVal;
    } copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: "Assuming manual retain/release" Thanks but as mentioned I'm using ARC.